# How to make the content of Expander visible to VisualTreeHelper

Tags: wpf, expander

I've put an Expander onto a Page. Within the expander there is a Label. After the page is loaded, the expander is not yet expanded. At this point, I inspect the Expander using VisualTreeHelper, I got a structure like this:

```
  Expander
    Border
      DockPanel
        ToggleButton
          Border
            Grid
              Ellipse
              Ellipse
              Path
              ContentPresenter
        ContentPresenter
```

where there is no Label under the last ContentPresenter.

However, Once the expander is expanded and then collapsed, I got the a different structure using VisualTreeHelper:

```
  Expander
    Border
      DockPanel
        ToggleButton
          Border
            Grid
              Ellipse
              Ellipse
              Path
              ContentPresenter
        ContentPresenter
          Label
            Border
              ContentPresenter
```

This time, the Label appears under the ContentPresenter.

It seems that as long as the expander has been expanded, VisualTreeHelper will know the contents within the Expander. But is there a possible way to make VisualTreeHelper be aware of Expander's contents without expanding it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method for forcing a control to load its contents programmatically.

I imagine you have some sort of recursive loop that searches through your elements. Before you call to get its children, use this call:

```
if (element is FrameworkElement)
     (element as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate()
```

That'll force it to apply its template and load the controls into memory. I imagine it is done this way for performance reasons, as controls are not normally needed until they are visible.

This approach also works for `TabControl` and any other control that can hide content, I believe.

Credit goes to Tao Liang who posted this solution over [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/693abf03-5042-4ab6-86e8-76aa24a496e9). Read it also if you're having trouble with your recursive loop.